# What change needs to make to the following code to set slide pause time of a jQuery slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, slider, slideshow

I'm using one jQuery image slider in my website. Following is the code I've written for image slider:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        var _SlideshowTransitions = [
        //Fade
        { $Duration: 1200, $Opacity: 2 }
        ];

        var options = {
            $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
            $AutoPlaySteps: 1,                                  //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), the default value is 1
            $Idle: 3000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
            $PauseOnHover: 1,                               //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, 4 freeze for desktop, 8 freeze for touch device, 12 freeze for desktop and touch device, default value is 1

            $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                          //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
            $SlideDuration: 500,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
            $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,                          //[Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20
            //$SlideWidth: 600,                                 //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container
            //$SlideHeight: 300,                                //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container
            $SlideSpacing: 0,                                   //[Optional] Space between each slide in pixels, default value is 0
            $DisplayPieces: 1,                                  //[Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
            $ParkingPosition: 0,                                //[Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.
            $UISearchMode: 1,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).
            $PlayOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to play slide (for auto play, navigation), 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 5 horizental reverse, 6 vertical reverse, default value is 1
            $DragOrientation: 3,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)

            $SlideshowOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable slideshow or not
                $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,                 //[Required] Class to create instance of slideshow
                $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,            //[Required] An array of slideshow transitions to play slideshow
                $TransitionsOrder: 1,                           //[Optional] The way to choose transition to play slide, 1 Sequence, 0 Random
                $ShowLink: true                                    //[Optional] Whether to bring slide link on top of the slider when slideshow is running, default value is false
            },

            $BulletNavigatorOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable navigator or not
                $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,                       //[Required] Class to create navigator instance
                $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                $AutoCenter: 1,                                 //[Optional] Auto center navigator in parent container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                $Steps: 1,                                      //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
                $Lanes: 1,                                      //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange items, default value is 1
                $SpacingX: 10,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                $SpacingY: 10,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                $Orientation: 1                                 //[Optional] The orientation of the navigator, 1 horizontal, 2 vertical, default value is 1
            },

            $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                $Steps: 1                                       //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
            }
        };
        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

        //responsive code begin
        //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
        function ScaleSlider() {
            var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
            if (parentWidth)
                jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(parentWidth, 940));
            else
                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
        }

        ScaleSlider();

        if (!navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|BlackBerry|IEMobile)/)) {
            $(window).bind('resize', ScaleSlider);
        }


        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad)/)) {
            $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
        }
        //responsive code end
    });
```

The above code is working perfect and fine for me. Now I want to set image pause time in this code. In other words I want to set time for which the slider image will be paused, the next image from slider will not appear. After completion of that much time the next image from image slider should come.

Actually i got confused with so many timer values set by default in above code. I'm not able to figure out exactly which parameter I've to modify in order to set the image pause time. So asking for your help.

Can someone please help me in making the necessary modification in my code and in achieving this functionality?

If you need any further information regarding the issue please do let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try `var _SlideshowTransitions = [
        
        { $Duration: 3000, $Opacity: 2 }
        ];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like

```
$Idle: 3000,
```

is the code. change 3000 with your value. 3000 is in milliseconds.
But I feel you should probably read the documentation first.

Comment: :Now I've modified my question with commented code. Now you might get better idea about where to make the necessary change.

Comment: Please try changing that code. put 7000 instead of 3000 to test. I think that is the code you are looking for.